# Ionic page onInit method called multiple times when navigating back and forth

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am developing an app where there is a home button and subsequent chain of pages(homepage->page1->page2) where user can navigate. Each page displays some information fetched from the server.

**Structure of the app**

There's a home page from where the user can navigate to say 'page 1' and from page 1 to page 2. There's a home button on every page, so when the user clicks on home button (say from page 1 to home page) and then goes again to page 1 and subsequently to page 2, the init method of page 2 (and the constructor) is called the number of times the user has visited the home page.

**Earlier**, this problem was occurring when we had a custom back button on page 2, so when the user went from page 2 to page 1 and back to page 2 the page constructor and init loaded multiple times (as many times as user navigates from page 2 to page 1 and back to page 2).

This got resolved when we opted to go for navBar's `backButton` using UIEvents.

I am not sure which code to post so please ask in comments any additional information which is needed.

Currently, my team is stuck on what's  cause of the problem, any hint regarding the same would be of great help.
Thanks!

P.S Problem also repeats when user navigates to home from page-1 using ionic's back button and then to page-1 -> page-2 (Init and constructors of page 2 are called the number of times user went to home from page1).

Comment: Suggest you post the custom back button function... how are you doing custom navigation?

Comment: Using `navctrl.push` and `navctrl.pop`

Comment: What version of Ionic are you using? When you created the pages, did you use the built-in page generators, i.e. `ionic generate page my-page`? How are you loading the pages, i.e. is each one encapsulated in its own module, or are they all part of the same module?

Comment: Ionic 3, yes we generated using built-in page generators, and every page has its module imported in 'AppModule'